# to enable chrome.commands in the current chrome stable release

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that plans to use Chrome's upcoming API [chrome.commands](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/commands.html) for defining global keyboard shortcuts.

This API will possibly be released in Chrome 25 ([says here](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/commands.html)) and it is currently available in Canary, Dev and Beta. (have tested on Canary but not tried on Dev or Beta yet).

My question is: is there a way to enable this API in the current stable version of Chrome? I have tried enabling "Experimental Extension APIs" but that is not helping.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a little bit more detail on why it is not possible. Is there an issue with enabling experimental API on a stable release, or is this something specific to the API chrome.commands, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Source Code of Say **23.0.1248.0** [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/releases/), you do not find references for these code!, So they are undefined in any older revisions.